# Add key to hash

Tags: javascript, hash

As you can see from my code I'm trying to add a key to a hash `page_rank`:

```js
var page_rank = {};

function create_page_rank_row(step, url, page_rank){
 if(page_rank[step]){

 }else{
  page_rank[step] = { urls: {}};
 }

 page_rank[step].urls[url] = page_rank;
};

create_page_rank_row(0, "d01", 3);
create_page_rank_row(0, "d02", 4);

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(page_rank);
```

```html
<p id="result">

</p>
```

But it won't work, I get the error:

`Cannot read property 'urls' of undefined`

**What do I wrong? How Can I fix that?** thanks

Comment: Can we see the JSON that page_rank starts as? I'm thinking that `page_rank[step]` may be set, but `page_rank[step].urls` is probably not, hence the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shadowing the initial `page_rank` variable with an argument that is also called `page_rank`.

When the function runs `page_rank` is set to a number. Look at the code when we inline the value of the arguments you are passing.

```
function create_page_rank_row(step, url, page_rank){
  if(3[step]){

  }else{
    3[step] = { urls: {}};
  }

  3[step].urls[url] = 3;
};
```

Javascript won't let you define new properties on simple primitive values such as numbers.

Maybe rename the outer variable to `page_ranks`.

Comment: Thanks! Really didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function with the page_rank argument as an integer, and accessing it with array bracketes. This will always return undefined, even if you set it.

```
var x = 3;
console.log(x[0]); //undefined
x[0] = 'something';
console.log(x[0]); //still undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var page_rank = {};

function create_page_rank_row(step, url, rank) {
  if (!page_rank.hasOwnProperty(step)) {
    page_rank[step] = {
      urls: {}
    };
  }

  page_rank[step].urls[url] = rank;
};

create_page_rank_row(0, "d01", 3);
create_page_rank_row(0, "d02", 4);

console.log(JSON.stringify(page_rank));
```

What is changed ? name of the third argument inside the function is changed & hasOwnProperty is added inside the function

Answer (score 0):

change

```
function create_page_rank_row(step, url, page_rank){
```

to

```
function create_page_rank_row(step, url, newrank){
```

and

```
page_rank[step].urls[url] = page_rank;
```

to

```
page_rank[step].urls[url] = newrank;
```